# Javascript: GTM Variable to cut and save part of a URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a custom Javascript variable in GTM that will cut part of the URL and return only that part:

https://www.domain.be/fr/

In this case, only what appears between the second "." and second "/" - the "be/fr/" bit

```
function() {
  var url = {{Page URL}};
  var new url = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(url"."),str.lastIndexOf(url"/"))
  return new url
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: 1. str is not defined. 2. lastIndexOf(url".") expects a comma between url and . 3. Variable name can not have spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do :

```
var myString = "https://www.domain.be/fr/";
var myRegexp = /https?:\/\/[^\/]+\.(\w+\/\w+)/;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Output:

```
be/fr
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, just replaced console with return match[1]